# If $p$ is irreducible, is $p(x^2)$ irreducible?

Tags: factoring, irreducible-polynomials

To show that a polynomial (over a field) of form $p(x^2)$ is irreducible, i was suggested to show that $p$ is irreducible and conclude from that that $p$ would be irreducible. For example take $q = x^4-16x^2+4$. Then $q = p(x^2)$ where $p=x^2-16x+4$. It is clear that $p$ is irreducible. However i can't see how this would imply that $q$ is also irreducible.

For example $x^4-x^2 = (x^2+x)(x^2-x)$ factors in a way that has non even powers of x in it. However $x^2-x$ still happens to be reducible in this case so it's not counterexample...

Comment: $x-1$ is irreducible but $x^2-1$ is not.

Comment: Should say:  your notation is not clear.  I think you just mean $p(x^2)$ but I am not sure.

Comment: Also, $x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible while $x^4 + x^2 + 1$ is not, even though the latter has no roots.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Are you asking "does $P(x)$ irreducible $\implies P(x^2)$ irreducible? "  or are you asking "does $P(x^2)$ irreducible $\implies P(x)$ irreducible?"  One of those claims is true, but only one.

Comment: $x$ is irreducible but $x^2=x\cdot x$.